# Get a DateTime by subtracting seconds from the current date

Tags: c#, datetime

I would like to subtract seconds from a date, for example:

Lets say I have 1300 seconds in a unsigned integer, I would like to take the current date and time, subtract 1,300 seconds from it, and end up with:

`01/13/2012 2:15 PM` (format doesn't really matter).

I did try:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(); 
dt.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, ui.OnlineTime)); 
Online.Text = dt.ToLongDateString();
```

Comment: You cannot convert a time span into a date. Try to think of it this way: I want to **add** (or remove) a time span of 1300 seconds to today's date.

Comment: I did try:

DateTime dt = new DateTime();

dt.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, ui.OnlineTime));

Online.Text = dt.ToLongDateString();

Comment: Your problem is that `DateTime` is immutable.  `Add` returns a new DateTime.  Also, use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`AddSeconds(double value)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `DateTime` takes positive and negative number of seconds:

> [`value` parameter represents] a number of whole and fractional seconds. The value parameter can be negative or positive.

Hence, to subtract 1300 seconds you need to add -1300 seconds:

```
DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1300);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1300);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1300)
```

That was easy

Comment: I think your comment had it right.  The author is correctly adding to their `DateTime`, the problem is that they're not saving the return value of the addition method they're calling.  So, calling `AddSeconds()` is really just half of the solution.

Comment: @BACON: I know.  I posted this answer before his comment.