# Set DateTime to 11:59:59 PM

Tags: c#, .net

We have an app which let's users get data between two dates. These dates are in a Date control and if the user wants to select data for one day they would enter in the same day in both controls.

This will cause an issue because the `.Value` of these controls is set to midnight, `12:00 AM`. So it will attempt to look for data between `12:00 AM` and `12:00 AM` of the same day.

For example,

```
DateTime start = fromDate.Value; // 09-07-2018 12:00 AM
DateTime end = toDate.Value; // 09-07-2018 12:00 AM
```

Later on, we will call the database where `start` is `:start` and `end` is `:end`.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN :start AND :end;
```

This query will return nothing as nothing is between midnight and midnight.

How do we set the `end` to `23:59:59` or `11:59:59 PM`?

Comment: There aren't 99 seconds in a minute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a DateTime by subtracting seconds from the current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858683/get-a-datetime-by-subtracting-seconds-from-the-current-date) `AddSeconds(-1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just use

```
DateTime end = toDate.Value.AddDays(1);
```

This will give you midnight of the next day, so anything less than this is the prior day.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use next code:

```
DateTime end = toDate.Value.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```